# Converting MySQL 5.6.10 - 32 bit to 64 bit version

Tags: mysql, windows, upgrade, mysql-5.6

I am currently using MySQL DB Version 5.6.10 for 32 bit running in 64 bit Window OS.I want to change it to 64 bit without taking any dump..Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

The data file format is the same for 32-bit and 64-bit editions of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Keith Murphy (co-author of the MySQL Administrator's Bible) quoted [here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/212533) doesn't appear to think that's very good idea - straight copying of binaries. I know that the quotation is quite old, but I, for one, would be very reticent to do something like that.

If I were you, I'd try the option at the beginning of the quote - pipe over a dump - I know that you don't want to do that, but it's possibly the best way.

> another option is to do a mysqldump and pipe it over to the new
>   server, e.g:
>   mysqldump --opt 32bitserver | mysql --host=64bithost -C
>   64bitserver