# How to do Mysql migration from 5.0 (320bit windows) to 5.6 (64 bit windows)?

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-5

I want migrate My Mysql 5.0 windows 32 bit to Mysql 5.6 Windows 64 bit?

Please suggest me the best way to do migration, i have around 10gb of data present in Mysql 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You use mysqldump.

Step 1. Dump your original 32 bit database. mysqldump my32bitdb [options...] > mydb.sql

Step 2. Copy the file mydb.sql to your new server

Step 3. Load the 32 bit database mysql -u root -p my64bitdb < C:\path\to\mydb.sql

With 10GB of data, it shouldn't take much more than ~ 1hr.

For reference, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers).

Comment: +1 because even if it is technically possible to do a binary upgrade, one version at a time, it is not worth the effort when the jump is so large. If you need an upgrade (almost) without downtime, use replication from the old to the new instance.

Comment: @jynus Thanks. See [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51363/converting-mysql-5-6-10-32-bit-to-64-bit-version/73943#73943) why I would be reticent to do any sort of binary upgrade - even though it is, as you point out, documented. Keith Murphy (author of the MySQL Administrator's Bible - his quote in the link) doesn't think it's a great idea. He thinks your idea is good though!

Comment: You are completely wrong there. Binary migration is completely possible beetween x86 and x86_64 without problem (as an Oracle employee told you on the link you mention), and something recommended and 100% supported between consecutive versions unless there is some specific problem. I wouldn't recommend it in this case because the jump between InnoDB (5.0) and InnoDB 1.1 is too large to be worth the time.

Comment: I specifically didn't say that it wasn't possible. I said that I'd be reticent to do it - I'd much prefer a text dump that I could eyeball. What I took from B. Keith Murphy's post is that although possible (as you rightly point out), it is better avoided if possible.

Comment: then you probably didn't have to upgrade many multi-terabyte MySQL servers. :-)

Comment: Indeed I didn't - I'm strictly in the amateur category compared to you, having only recently started to engage with MySQL and Open Source generally (previously an Oracle DBA).